# Colorized tail: How to set default color

Tags: sed, colors, escape-characters, tail

I have a function setup to provide color to the tail command using ANSI escape sequences with sed.

```
function colortail {
tail -f -n30 $1 | sed -e 's/\(.*MINOR.*\)/\o033[93m\1\o033[39m/' -e 's/.*MAJOR.*/\o033[38;5;202m&\o033[m/' 
}
```

How can I set this up so that any other lines that do not match my predefined strings are in another color? Like a "default color"? Is there a way to wildcard this? Would adding something like this work if I wanted bright/bold white?

```
-e 's/\(.*"".*\)033[1;37m\033[m"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very good with shell escape sequences, but it seems to me that you are. I assume that what you're missing for your use-case, therefore, is to implement if/else-type logic. Here's one way you can do it:

```
sed -e '\
        /.*MINOR.*/{ # If .*MINOR.* is matched \
            # Code to set MINOR color \
        } \
        /.*MINOR.*/!{ # If .*MINOR.* is not matched \
            /.*MAJOR.*/ { # If .*MAJOR.* is matched \
            # Code to set MAJOR color \
            } \
            /.*MAJOR.*/!{ # If .*MAJOR.* is not matched \
            # Code to set the default color \
            } \
         }'
```

**Reference**

- [If/Else Testing in sed](http://www.pement.org/sed/ifelse.txt)

Comment: I hadn't thought about that but I think I can build off of it. I will give it a shot.